# Recommendations for visual studio package management in the Enterprise

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Our development team uses Nuget and SVN currently. We have problems with unwanted Package restores that silently and uncontrolably replaces the references in our shared projects. (we also have an automated build process)

Can someone recommend add-ons, tools or proven best-practices or strategies for secure management of the external references, their versioning (and possbly visualization of the dependency graphs.) ?

Comment: This will likely be closed since it's off-topic according to [point 4 in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You *could* make it on-topic by describing in more detail the issues you're having and how you attempted to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

> We have problems with unwanted Package restores that silently and uncontrolably replaces the references in our shared projects

I may misunderstand your point but it sounds like if you are saying that package restore changes the references in your project file. That seems like a bug. NuGet shouldn't upgrade packages nor touch your project files when doing a package restore -- it should only restore the exact versions as described in your `packages.config`.

As far as enterprise environments go, you probably don't want your build talking over the internet to NuGet.org. You can achieve this by providing a `nuget.config` file that removes the ambient package sources and only provide a specific package source that points to, say, an internal network share. You could also have a shared location thats in your version control that contains all the packages. That's what we did internally for building our NuGet packages.

Does this help?

Comment: Correct - we have many developers doing package restores slightly differently. But it is great to hear that a company as large as Microsoft is using Nuget package restores successfully. We will keep up the work.